# rails how to draw view object response on sequence diagram

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, sequence, diagram

anyone can give example how to draw rails app sequence diagram? 
i have trying draw myself, but confuse at the view object. at rails view classes are isn't exist right?

for example i have :

```
apps/controller/productsController.rb
apps/model/product.rb
apps/views/product/index.html.erb
```

so if there is a request on product page (index action on productsController)
wtih this sequence

1. index action/method find all product, assigined to @products
2. the products controller render the index view
3. the index.html.erb response by displaying products to browser

how draw sequence diagram for that request and response(for example)?

if i missunderstanding something in theory/terminology, let me know

Comment: Where is your problem? Place the instances and send the messages as you lined them up.

Comment: thanks for your reply. rails is a MVC framework, but view object on rails isnt exist right?
 so in sequence diagram, the view objects are refer to what object? the erb files?

Comment: The View is an object like any else. It's just moved a bit out of sight in Rails.

Comment: if it hidden, if there is a operation displaying data to user,  how i send the data through message from controller to view ?  passing it as parameter? but in the view obj not have method or class right? it just a html/erb code. would you mind give me a example so i can understand. really appeciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it will look like this:

[image]

The erb rendering is just shown as internal call `renderErb` in the controller. The result of this rendering is brought to the view with the `renderHtml`. I did not use the exact nomenclature of Rails, but basically that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a diagram possibility exists, at least not automatically. 
You can use either `railroady` or `rails-erd` to generate a UML and ERD diagrams.. but for a complete Controller -> Model -> View you might have to do it manually.

https://github.com/preston/railroady 
https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd

Comment: thanks. 
and yes, i've to draw complete mvc sequence diagram manualy